# In Rails, how can I stub a websocket message for a test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, capybara, minitest

The application is using Minitest on Rails 4 with Capybara.

I'd like to write an integration or feature test that stubs a websocket connection (the application uses Faye as a client) to return a specific message (like I'm used to doing with Webmock).

Is this possible? If so, can you provide an example? My research has not turned up any examples.

Comment: Your research hasn't shown up any examples because it's not really what you're supposed to be doing in feature tests.  Feature tests are supposed to be end-to-end black box tests where you configure the data as required for the app to generate the desired results and then all interaction is done via the browser (no mocking/stubbing). If you need to set the response from an external app, implement a fake of that app and use that instead.

Comment: "Implement a fake of that app and use that instead." Isn't that what a mock/stub would be doing? I'd prefer my test not be dependent on the actual external service.

Comment: No - a mock/stub changes your actual apps code (by monkey patching in results)- a fake is a separate small app that replaces/pretends to be your external service - you could also implement a fake with a programmable proxy like puffing-billy - although that may not work for websockets.

Comment: I trust your judgment but I'm not sure I follow your reasoning. True, a stub monkey patches the result. But it all will be done within the context of a test and for the unit of code I want to put under test, I don't see why it would matter which approach I use. I'd prefer a mock simply because it seems simpler and more convenient (the mock library is already present in the app). Now if it's not possible to mock websockets, I could see that being a critical consideration. Is there some other principle I'm missing with my question? Is it because I'm referring to it as a feature test?

Comment: To answer my own question posed at the end of my last comment: I am missing an important point. Once the page loads, the Rails app's work is finished. At that point, the page is being uploaded based on the websocket interactions between the JS Faye client (in the user's browser) and the message service (a completely different server). Since the Rails app is not involved, trying to monkey-patch it is pointless. So how to test this? As 
@ThomasWalpole stated: "Implement a fake of that app and use that instead." It's not how I'd like to do it. But now it makes sense.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Thanks again for your help. If you'd like to summarize your comments in an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your research hasn't shown up any examples because it's not really what you're supposed to be doing in feature tests. Feature tests are supposed to be end-to-end black box tests where you configure the data as required for the app to generate the desired results and then all interaction is done via the browser (no mocking/stubbing which technically alter your apps code).  Additionally when connections between the browser and a 3rd party service are involved there is nowhere in your app where you can mock it.

It may be possible to stub a websocket connection from the browser with  a programmable proxy like puffing-billy, however it's generally cleaner to produce a small fake version of the 3rd party service for testing purposes (sinatra app, etc) and point the browser at that rather than the original service when you need to craft custom responses. Additionally, there are a lot of fakes already out there, depending on what service you are using (fake-stripe, fake-s3, etc), which may provide the functionality you're looking for.